# Hi everybody. I'm making a shop with django and i have a problem with custom User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

When I'm trying to delete my ShopUser i have this exception

I have not found a solution to this problem on the internet

```
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such table: account_shopuser_groups
```

Also this exception resises when I want to migrate.

How can i solve this problem?

My CustomUserModel:

```
class ShopUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)


    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(
        _('superuser status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates that this user has all permissions without '
            'explicitly assigning them.'
        ),
    )
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

my CustomUserAdmin

```
class ShopUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = ShopUserCreationForm
    form = ShopUserChangeForm
    model = ShopUser

    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(ShopUser, ShopUserAdmin)
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: The deleting procedure is looking for account_shopuser_groups table which doesn't exist. You have certainly forgotten run some migration command during your Django installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *[`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/)* your models before using them.

Run **`makemigrations`** to create the migrations

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations account
```

Then run **`migrate`** to push them to your db:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

### Edit:

You probably have an issue with your migration graph.  If you don't care about the data in your database, the easiest way fix this is to delete your migrations, delete the database, then rerun your initial migrations.  The following command will clear your migrations for you (unix-like OS only):

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -path "*/site-packages/*" -delete;
```

If you are on windows you will have to manually go to *each* of your application's migration folders, and delete every file.

Afterwards make sure you delete your `db.sqlite3` file (or the schema for whatever database you are using), then run the migrations again.

Comment: when i migrate raise the same exception

Comment: @glebabusya did set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting?

Comment: @glebabusya also, is this your initial migration?

Comment: Yes, AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings. No, it isn't inital migration

Comment: @glebabusya  is this your initial migration?